# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 22

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a function in MySQL:

Here is the SQL code:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION hranisez_wp.calcBMI
(
    cPol     varchar,
    dPregled datetime,
    dRodjen  datetime,
    nVisina  double,
    nTezina  double;
)
returns varchar(4000)
begin
declare nBMI         double;
declare nStarost     double;
declare cBMIText     varchar(100);
declare nPothranjen  double;
declare nMrsav       double;
declare nNormalan    double;
declare nGojazan     double;
declare nPrekomjeran double;
declare nMinTezina   double;
declare nMaxTezina   double;
declare exit handler for sqlexception begin return(null);
 end
//

DELIMITER ;
```

And I am getting this error all the time:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' dPregled datetime, dRodjen datetime, nVisina double, nTez' at line 3
```

Please help!

Comment: StackOverflow is NOT a debugging service. Read the error message, it contains the info you need to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three errors in your SQL

- You have a `;` after the last parameter
- `varchar` need a length parameter
- The `exit handler` has no `end;` for the handler body

So try this:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION hranisez_wp.calcBMI
(
    cPol     varchar(50),
    dPregled datetime,
    dRodjen  datetime,
    nVisina  double,
    nTezina  double
)
returns varchar(4000)
begin
declare nBMI         double;
declare nStarost     double;
declare cBMIText     varchar(100);
declare nPothranjen  double;
declare nMrsav       double;
declare nNormalan    double;
declare nGojazan     double;
declare nPrekomjeran double;
declare nMinTezina   double;
declare nMaxTezina   double;
declare exit handler for sqlexception begin return(null); end;
end
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks to @Martin for correcting my english syntax error. :-)

Answer (score 2):

No parameter specify for varchar. Varchar datatype requires parameters e.g cPol varchar(50),
Which determined the data length in the column.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `;` from  `nTezina  double;` also remove `returns varchar(4000)` and check again